# How do i cherry pick which values I want from my X-macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros, x-macros

I have an x-macro like this

```
#define LIST_OF_REGISTERS_R16 \
    X(0x00, B) \
    X(0x10, D) \
    X(0x20, H) \
    X(0x30, S)
```

and I define it like so

```
#define X(id, name) name--;
    LIST_OF_REGISTERS_R16
#undef X
```

the problem is that in certain cases when I'm defining the macro, I need to sometimes select or deselect certain parts of this list, like I might need only `B, D, H`(without the S) or I might need `B,D,S`(without the H). I could define an x-macro for every possible combination but then I'd have 24 X-macros just for certain scenarios which is ugly and wasteful. Any help?

Comment: Can you generate all the combinations and just ignore the ones you don't need?

Comment: Hm. How do you want to use the X macro? A typical use would be to define things together that are separate concepts in C, e.g. enumerated constants and strings. n my experience, X macros are used for definitions rather than code. Your definition of `name--` suggests that you have something else in mind, perhaps an array of four elements that you can index with the constants `B`, `D`, `H`and `S`?

Comment: @MOehm it's actually for an assignment operation, so it would be `#define X(id, name) case id: var_example = name--; break;`, and in the list there are a lot more than just B, D, H, S(around 10) which is why I didn't want to generate the macro for all possible combinations. The goal is fairly simple enough, since I just need to perform an assignment, but the problem is that it is not maintainable and simple which is why I was trying to use X-macros

Comment: @Barmar that won't be feasible in my code, what I provided above in the examples was the minimal example, but in reality the list contains 10, so generating an entire list for all those changes seems insane. I was hoping for maybe a somewhat simple way to just exclude one element of that list for a certain scenario/case

Answer (score 0):

You could use use an `if` statement.

```
#define LIST_OF_REGISTERS_R16(X) \
    X(0x00, B) \
    X(0x10, D) \
    X(0x20, H) \
    X(0x30, S)

#define X(a, b) if constexpr (#b[0] == 'S') std::cout << a << '\n';

int main()
{
    LIST_OF_REGISTERS_R16(X);
}
```

however, if you're picking single registers out of the list, you're imho better of defining seperate macros for those.

```
#define REGISTER_R16_B(X) X(0x00, B)
#define REGISTER_R16_D(X) X(0x10, D)
#define REGISTER_R16_H(X) X(0x20, H)
#define REGISTER_R16_S(X) X(0x30, S)

#define LIST_OF_REGISTERS_R16(X) \
    REGISTER_R16_B(X) \
    REGISTER_R16_D(X) \
    REGISTER_R16_H(X) \
    REGISTER_R16_S(X)

#define X(a, b) std::cout << a << '\n';

int main()
{
    REGISTER_R16_S(X);
}
```